# Updateing txt file after unset

Tags: php, string

The problem is that removeBlog removes all the lines instead line by line.
I think i have it wrong with foreach/fwrite part.
Here comes the class Message:

```
 class Message
{
protected $blogLista=[];
protected $file = "blog_tmp/blogdata.txt";

function __construct()
{
    if(file_exists($this->file)) {
        $txt = fopen($this->file,"r");
        while (!feof($txt)) {
            $line = fgets($txt);
            if (!empty($line)) {
                $line_arr = explode(",", $line);
                $obj = new Blog ($line_arr[0], $line_arr[1], $line_arr[2]);
                $this->blogLista[] = $obj;
            }
        }
        fclose($txt);
    }

  }

  function addBlog($nam,$mes,$dat){
    $txtx=fopen($this->file,"a");
    fwrite($txtx, "$nam,$mes,$dat".PHP_EOL);
    fclose($txtx);
 }

 function removeBlog($ind){
    unset($this->blogLista[$ind]);
    $var=fopen($this->file,"w+");
    //fwrite($var,$this->blogLista);

    foreach ($this->blogLista as $key=>$val){
        fwrite($var,"$val->getName(),$val->getMessage,$val->getDate") ;
    }


    fclose($var);
  }


  function getBlogLista(){
    return $this->blogLista;
  }
}
```

The problem is that removeBlog removes all the lines instead line by line.
I think i have it wrong with foreach/fwrite part.
Here comes the class Blog part:

```
 class Blog
 {

  protected $name='';
  protected $message='';
  protected $date='';

  function __construct($nam,$mes,$dat)
  {
    $this->name=$nam;
    $this->message=$mes;
    $this->date=$dat;
}

function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

function getMessage(){
    return $this->message;
 }

 function getDate(){
    return $this->date;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the issue you're encountering. Aside from `fwrite($var,"$val->getName(),$val->getMessage,$val->getDate") ;` should be `fwrite($var, $val->getName() . ',' . $val->getMessage() . ',' . $val->getDate());` We need to know what's wrong and what you're wanting to accomplish. See [this example](https://3v4l.org/THsNR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing brackets `()` when you're trying to call methods, and you cannot call methods inside double quotes like this<sup>[1]</sup>.

Try to replace by:

```
fwrite($var,$val->getName().','.$val->getMessage().','.$val->getDate()) ;
```

Instead of :

```
fwrite($var,"$val->getName(),$val->getMessage,$val->getDate") ;
```

<sub>[1] See the comment of @NigelRen</sub>

Comment: Just to say you can call methods inside double quotes, but you have to use braces... `echo "{$val->getName()},{$val->getMessage()},{$val->getDate()}";`.  Voted up anyway as I was going to answer virtually the same thing.

Comment: @NigelRen You're right! Thank you. I've update the anwser :)